# Deploying Microsoft.Maps/account

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have used an ARM Template to deploy a Microsoft.Maps/account resource to Azure.

That was successful:

```
Resource Microsoft.Maps/accounts 'nzmoebasedemo0000bt' provisioning status is succeeded
```

I'd like to retrieve the Primary key generated, within the ARM template, in order to persist it to a KeyVault.

I looked in https://resource.azure.com but the Maps/account provider was not listed, so could find no hint as to what property to read.

I tried:

```
[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Maps/account', 'parameters('keyVaultVaultSecretMapsAccountResourceName')'), providers('Microsoft.Maps', 'account').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]"
```

Abd got back:

```
@{parameters=; status=Trial run failed. ; outputs=; provisionStateSucceeded=False; deploymentOutput=; errorCode=InvalidTemplate; errorMessage=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'azure.arm.base.keyVault.vault.secret' at line '168' and column '9' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'providers': function requires the second argument to be a multi-segmented resource type excluding the resource provider namespace. Invalid function argument 'account'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#providers for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.}
```

Which in this case...seems incorrect.

What am I not seeing/getting?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

As per suggestion given, the following did pass a test run.

```
"[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Maps/account', parameters('keyVaultVaultSecretMapsAccountResourceName')), '2018-05-01').keys[0].value]"
```

But when actually run, got the following:

```
1:02:35 AM - Resource Microsoft.Maps/account 'nzmoebasedemo0000bt' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidResourceType",
    "message": "The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Maps' for api version '2018-05-01'."
  }
}'
```

**Edit again:**

As per guidance given in the comments, the following works! (after correcting api version, spelling mistake, and using 'primaryKey' property:

```
"[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Maps/accounts', parameters('keyVaultVaultSecretMapsAccountsResourceName')), '2018-05-01').primaryKey]"
```

Comment: just hardcore the api version. MS discourages such usage

Comment: Yes...as far as I can tell... (I've correct the question to better show what I've tried).

Comment: @4c74356b41 that got me closer -- but as per edited question, still missing something...

Comment: can you try this version: `2017-01-01-preview`

Comment: Just tried. Same results :-(

Comment: you have a typo there, its `accounts`, not `account`

Comment: Ah. Man. That's embarrassing ! :-) Even at 1.15am... Trying again right now...

Comment: @user9314395 -- you deserve the credit! Thanks!!! Night...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was due to a typo, the provider\resource is `Microsoft.Maps/accounts`